# Unresolved project references only on first load of a solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, project-reference

**Short description:** First load of a solution will mark external project references as invalid, reloading the solution fix the problem.

**Detailed description:**

We have a large amount of C# projects in our system, with several different solutions containing only a small number of projects. The projects are referencing each other via project references instead of direct reference to the dll. The referenced projects are not part of the solution.

I experience a strange behavior when using these solutions: every time I open a solution for the **first time**, these external project references are marked as *invalid* under the References tree, and some features are not working properly (for example Code analysis, ReSharper references, etc.) Building the solution is possible without errors. However, when I **reload** the solution, all references will be *valid* again.

Additional infos:

- If I change something in one of the project file, which triggers a reload of the project in the solution, the references are broken again, and I have to reload the solution twice to fix them.
- If I add the external projects to the solution, than the problem does not appear.
- If I close Visual Studio and load the last solution on next start, the references will be valid. Only loading another solution triggers the problem.

Although the problem is not crucial, it is very inconvenient and time consuming.

We are using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0 (Visual Studio 2012 is also installed).

Comment: What do you mean by _external project_? Is that a **solution project** or a **reference** to a component like an assembly? By external you mean that your external _thing_ is not under your solution.. where is it? (GAC?)

Comment: Simply it is a *project reference* to a project, which is not in the solution. It is included in other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this package in all your projects.

It happened to me something similar. I added to a solution project which already have another solution, and the references were wrong.

This package solve this issue, at least for me.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGetReferenceHintPathRewrite